# Cannot install Google Web Toolkit Developer Plugin in Google Chrome

Tags: gwt, google-chrome-extension

I am using Windows XP SP2 and Chrome (version 9.0.597.19) but every time I run gwt in developer mode I see:
"Development Mode requires the Google Web Toolkit Developer Plugin..."
No matter how many times I install it.

How can it be that gwt developer mode is not running in google's own chrome in xp sp2??  This is outrageous??!! It is working in FF but is very slow.

Comment: Windows! Did you try rebooting:p (Just kidding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Web Toolkit plugin is for Firefox 3.5.x and 3.6.x and

probably Google Chrome 7. I'm also using Chrome (version 9.0.597.19) which doesn't support GWT plugin

Answer (score 2):

Do you have Click-to-activate-plugins enabled in Chrome? I had, and I had to click on the little puzzle piece in the URL-bar and select that all plugins may run on 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem. Every time I clicked *"Download the GWT Developer Plugin
For Chrome"* it would start to load and then just stop without anything happening. Eventually I opened the link in a new tab and got a captcha with this message:

*"Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and not a robot."*

Maybe you are having the same problem?